# PHP - Edit page , How to set default dropdownlist that have option from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I know only this method. this method is assume that you know the values in all `<option>`

```
<select name="agama" id="agama">
    <option value="Islam"<?php if ($rows['agama'] === 'Islam') echo ' selected="selected"'>Islam</option>
    <option value="Khatolik"<?php if ($rows['agama'] === 'Khatolik') echo ' selected="selected"'>Khatolik</option>
    <option value="Protestan"<?php if ($rows['agama'] === 'Protestan') echo ' selected="selected"'>Protestan</option>
    <option value="Hindu"<?php if ($rows['agama'] === 'Hindu') echo ' selected="selected"'>Hindu</option>
    <option value="Buddha"<?php if ($rows['agama'] === 'Buddha') echo ' selected="selected"'>Buddha</option>
    <option value="Lain-Lain"<?php if ($rows['agama'] === 'Lain-Lain') echo ' selected="selected"'>Lain-Lain</option>
</select>
```

.... the above code is example from other people  not mine.

but My case is the `<option>` is select from database too.

- I have 2 table, oav_event  and oav_album
- the oav_album has foreign key (event_id)  from oav_event table
- I want to check if row['event_id'] from oav_album table is equal to option value (from oav_event  table) if true, then set `selected="selected"`

  ```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>" >Event: <?php echo $row['event_date']; ?> </option>
  <?php } ?>
  ```

the option will change depend on change in database table, so I don't know the value in option.  How should I do?

Comment: Okay loop create your select box so where is the variable which contain value from database which should be selected.

Comment: What is the default value you want to keep selected?

Comment: Yes same thing what i want to know so we can help you.

Comment: ok I update the question please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="event_id">
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM oav_event";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $selected = "";
      if($row['event_id'] == $Yourmatchvalue)
      {
       $selected = "selected";
      }
     ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>" selected="<?php echo $selected; ?>" >Event: <?php echo $row['event_date']; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

may this helps your. you need to replace $Yourmatchvalue variable with your variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_GET` as the method on your form and pass the `id` of the record using it:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
     if (!empty($_GET['event_id']) && $row['event_id'] == $_GET['event_id']) {
        $selected = 'selected = "selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["event_id"].'">'.$row["event_date"].'</option>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution,

```
$selected_value = 'Hindu'; // This will come from database
```

Change option tag with this

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>" <?php echo ($row['event_id'] == $selected_value) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> >Event: <?php echo $row['event_date']; ?> </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one function which will create options list like this:

```
function setDropdownValue($selectQueue_list,$selectedVal) 
{
    $queueVal = '';

    $selectQueue_list_res=$db->query($selectQueue_list);            

    while($selectQueue_list_res_row=$db->fetchByAssoc($selectQueue_list_res))       
    {
        $val  = $selectQueue_list_res_row['id'];
        $name = $selectQueue_list_res_row['name'];

        if($val == $selectedVal)
        {
            $queueVal .= "<option value='$val' selected='selected' label='$name'>$name</option>";
        }
        else
        {
            $queueVal .= "<option value='$val' label='$name'>$name</option>";
        }
    }
    return $queueVal;
}
```

Then create a query:

```
$get_value_query="SELECT id, name FROM table";

$dropdown_selected_value = !empty($dropdown_value) ? $dropdown_value: ''; // Pass value which you want to be selected in dropdown
```

Then call this function:

```
$dropdown_options = setDropdownValue($get_value_query, $dropdown_selected_value);
```

Later when you get dropdown options in `$dropdown_options`, use jquery to populate the dropdown, like this:

```
$('#dropdown_select_id').html("$dropdown_options");
```

Give it a try, and let me know.